# grep searching multiple strings in a file

Tags: regex, r

How can we grep files with only name  "log2.read.counts.2289_Tail" from a list of files.

data =

```
"log2.read.counts.2289_12_Tumor_NF4_CTTGTAA_L002" 
"log2.read.counts.2289_1_Tail_cont_ATCACGA_L002"   
"log2.read.counts.2289_2_Tail_Lmyc_CGATGTA_L002"        
"log2.read.counts.2289_3_Tail_Nfib_TTAGGCA_L002"        
 "log2.read.counts.2289_4_Cell_LmycS3_TGACCAA_L002"
```

output =

```
     "log2.read.counts.2289_1_Tail_cont_ATCACGA_L002"   
     "log2.read.counts.2289_2_Tail_Lmyc_CGATGTA_L002"   
     "log2.read.counts.2289_3_Tail_Nfib_TTAGGCA_L002"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grepl() returns TRUE if the search is matched. Use this to filter your input vector. If you aren't familiar with regular expressions, it's probably wise to spend some time learning them. In this case. It's searching for your string, with one or more numbers in the middle.

```
input <- c("log2.read.counts.2289_12_Tumor_NF4_CTTGTAA_L002", 
           "log2.read.counts.2289_1_Tail_cont_ATCACGA_L002",   
           "log2.read.counts.2289_2_Tail_Lmyc_CGATGTA_L002",        
           "log2.read.counts.2289_3_Tail_Nfib_TTAGGCA_L002",        
           "log2.read.counts.2289_4_Cell_LmycS3_TGACCAA_L002" )
> input[grepl("log2\\.read\\.counts\\.2289_[0-9]+_Tail", input)]
[1] "log2.read.counts.2289_1_Tail_cont_ATCACGA_L002"
[2] "log2.read.counts.2289_2_Tail_Lmyc_CGATGTA_L002"
[3] "log2.read.counts.2289_3_Tail_Nfib_TTAGGCA_L002"
```

Comment: The periods should probably be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with `grep`:

```
fls <- c("log2.read.counts.2289_12_Tumor_NF4_CTTGTAA_L002", 
"log2.read.counts.2289_1_Tail_cont_ATCACGA_L002",   
"log2.read.counts.2289_2_Tail_Lmyc_CGATGTA_L002",        
"log2.read.counts.2289_3_Tail_Nfib_TTAGGCA_L002",        
"log2.read.counts.2289_4_Cell_LmycS3_TGACCAA_L002")

grep("^log2\\.read.counts\\.2289_\\d+_Tail", fls, value=TRUE)

## [1] "log2.read.counts.2289_1_Tail_cont_ATCACGA_L002"
## [2] "log2.read.counts.2289_2_Tail_Lmyc_CGATGTA_L002"
## [3] "log2.read.counts.2289_3_Tail_Nfib_TTAGGCA_L002"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a list of files already:
ls -1 | grep "log2.read.counts.2289_[0-9]{1,}_Tail"

[0-9]{1.} will match any length number sequences (in your example they are all single digit - 1, 2, 3 - but this will match 23 and 34 as well for example).

The periods need to be escaped since they have a special meaning (on its own a period will match a single preceding character).

Answer (score -2):

grep '^log2.read.counts.2289_*Tail*'